# How to set headers globally for specific url after get from login service using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this login service:

```
var url =  GetHostUrl.cvmUrl+'/WSUser/users/login';
$http({
  method  : 'POST',
  url     : url,
  data    : $.param({
           username:$scope.user_name,
           password:$scope.pass,
           domain: GetHostUrl.cvmServerUpdated
  }), 
  headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
})
.success(function(data){
   $localstorage.authtoken = data.authtoken;
}
```

Have to pass `$localstorage.authtoken` in headers globally for the specific URL.

Answer (score 2):

There is a feature in AngularJs to intercept all incoming requests and responses, these are hooks that can be triggered before you make a http request or when you receive one. you can add the Auth header to the request and your request should be successful.

more info on [Angular Interceptors](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/)

Comment: Actually login service is in other controller, after getting the data from login service have to inject the response to the other controller. i.e, app.js. In app.js it loads at first before getting the response from the login service.

Comment: are u using ui- router?

Comment: Yes am using ui-router

Comment: Cant able to inject the service response to factory which was placed in app.js(Common JS file). Anyother way to proceed instead of removing the uirouter. @syed faizan

Comment: Correct headers can be easily set over there

Comment: No need to remove ui-router, in the outgoing request middleware , check the url property, u add the auth token to the requests to those requests

Answer (score 0):

Create a Service for making the HTTP calls and use that service to get the $http object.

you can manipulate the request at a single place according to your need

your service code will be something like this

```
HTTPService={}
HTTPService.method="";
HTTPService.url="";
HTTPService.headers={}
//modify the headers over here
HTTPService.call=function(){
 return $http({
   method  : HTTPService.method,
   url     : HTTPService.url,
 )}
}
return HTTPService;
```

and use this service's call method to make call across your application.

I can also post the exact same code if this code is unclear.

I would suggest you to create on you own.
So Your Login Service can use HTTPService Service to make http call so that method body is at one place.

You can override the values for the specific URL as required

Comment: I already set header properties to all the url. I have to add one common property for the header to the specific url

Comment: so change the header accordingly by overriding the default values the common servic and make the **http** call.

your LoginService will extend the HTTPService and use HTTPService.call method to make http calls